# Alignment problem with superscript before \pm symbol in tables

Tags: tables, alignment

First, a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}
\sisetup{table-align-text-post=true,
    table-space-text-post  =
    \textsuperscript{\emph{a}}}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-align-text-post=true,
    table-space-text-post  =
    \textsuperscript{\emph{a}}}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Esto es el título}
    \label{resultados}
    \begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{
            @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
            l
            l
            S[table-format=2.1(2)]
            S[table-format=3.1(3)]
        }
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries{Condiciones}} & {\bfseries{RCT (\si{\minute})}} & {\bfseries{$\mathbf{G'_{60}}$ (\si{\pascal})}}\\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{{\bfseries{Parámetro A}}} & Alta & 7.9$^a$\pm1.3 & 74.6\pm6.7 \\
        & Media & 15.4$^b$ \pm0.9 & 57.7\pm5.0 \\
        & Baja  & 31.8$^c$ \pm0.5 & 26.9\pm2.3 \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{{\bfseries{Parámetro B}}} & Alta & 14.6\pm1.9 & 76.8\pm1.8 \\
        & Media & 15.4\pm0.9 & 57.7\pm5.0 \\
        & Baja  & 19.8\pm0.3 & 29.9\pm1.3 \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{{\bfseries{Parámetro C}}} & Alto & 15.4\pm0.9  & 57.7\pm5.0\\
        & Bajo  & 4.9\pm0.5  & 135.2\pm12.8 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}\\\smallskip
    \parbox{0.8\textwidth}{
        \scriptsize Valores medios $\pm$ desviación estándar de tres réplicas. Medias con letras distintas son significativamente diferentes (test de Tukey, $p<0.05$).}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

As you can see, there is a problem with the alignment of the superscript letters before the `\pm` symbol. I've been reading here if someone already had this problem but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks to all the suggestions you could give me.

A MWE with another problem related with the previous one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\emph{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{Esto es el título}
\label{resultados}

\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  l
  S[table-format=2.1(2),
    table-align-text-post=true,
    table-space-text-post=\tnote{a},
   ]
  S[table-format=3.1(3),
  table-align-text-post=true,
  table-space-text-post=\tnote{a}
  ]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries{Condiciones}} &
{\bfseries{RCT (\si{\minute})}} &
{\bfseries{$\mathbf{G'_{60}}$ (\si{\pascal})}}\\
\midrule
\bfseries Parámetro A & Alta  &  7.9\pm1.3\tnote{a} & 74.6\pm6.7\tnote{a} \\
                      & Media & 15.4\pm0.9\tnote{b} & 57.7\pm5.0\tnote{b} \\
                      & Baja  & 31.8\pm0.5\tnote{c} & 26.9\pm2.3\tnote{c} \\
\midrule
\bfseries Parámetro B & Alta  & 14.6\pm1.9 &   76.8\pm1.8 \\
                      & Media & 15.4\pm0.9 &   57.7\pm5.0 \\
                      & Baja  & 19.8\pm0.3 &   29.9\pm1.3 \\
\midrule
\bfseries Parámetro C & Alto  & 15.4\pm0.9  &  57.7\pm5.0\tnote{a}\\
                      & Bajo  &  4.9\pm0.5  & 135.2\pm12.8\tnote{b} \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}
\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{%
  \scriptsize Valores medios $\pm$ desviación estándar de tres réplicas. 
  Medias con letras distintas son significativamente diferentes (test de 
  Tukey, $p<0.05$).}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

There is a bad alignment of the superscripts when the digits of the error are different, in this example in the right column I have the majority of the error data with two digits, but one with three. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You can't have the note between the main part and the uncertainty (and it wouldn't really make sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note mark should follow the full number:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\emph{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{Esto es el título}
\label{resultados}

\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  l
  S[table-format=2.1(2),
    table-align-text-post=true,
    table-space-text-post=\tnote{a},
   ]
  S[table-format=3.1(3)]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries{Condiciones}} &
{\bfseries{RCT (\si{\minute})}} &
{\bfseries{$\mathbf{G'_{60}}$ (\si{\pascal})}}\\
\midrule
\bfseries Parámetro A & Alta  &  7.9\pm1.3\tnote{a} & 74.6\pm6.7 \\
                      & Media & 15.4\pm0.9\tnote{b} & 57.7\pm5.0 \\
                      & Baja  & 31.8\pm0.5\tnote{c} & 26.9\pm2.3 \\
\midrule
\bfseries Parámetro B & Alta  & 14.6\pm1.9 &   76.8\pm1.8 \\
                      & Media & 15.4\pm0.9 &   57.7\pm5.0 \\
                      & Baja  & 19.8\pm0.3 &   29.9\pm1.3 \\
\midrule
\bfseries Parámetro C & Alto  & 15.4\pm0.9  &  57.7\pm5.0\\
                      & Bajo  &  4.9\pm0.5  & 135.2\pm12.8 \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}
\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{%
  \scriptsize Valores medios $\pm$ desviación estándar de tres réplicas. 
  Medias con letras distintas son significativamente diferentes (test de 
  Tukey, $p<0.05$).}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid `\multirow` that doesn't add to readability; in my opinion it hinders it, actually.

Comment: Thanks! You were very clear, I'd take all your recommendations.

Comment: I've found the solution to the second problem, just put table-align-text-post=false in sisetup of the last column.